# How to Reduce An Array of Objects That Contain Matching Keys/Values + Variations?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the best way to reduce this array of objects to get the desired result?

```
const arr = [
  {
          "id": "561",
          "count": "1",
          "month": 7
      },
      {
          "id": "561",
          "count": "1",
          "month": 7
      },
      {
          "id": "561",
          "count": "-1",
          "month": 8
      },
      {
          "id": "561",
          "count": "1",
          "month": 9
      },
      {
          "id": "561",
          "count": "-1",
          "month": 9
      }
  ]
```

As you can see the id matches and some of the months match. What I would like to achieve is something along the lines of:

```
[
  {
    "id": "561",
    "count": 2
    "month": 7
  },
  {
    "id": "561",
    "count": -1,
    "month": 8
  },
  {
    "id": "561",
    "count": 0,
    "month": 9
  }
]
```

I'm basically trying to get the total count by month per id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to group and evaluate your array based on id and month

```js
const arr = [
  {
          "id": "561",
          "count": "1",
          "month": 7
      },
      {
          "id": "561",
          "count": "1",
          "month": 7
      },
      {
          "id": "561",
          "count": "-1",
          "month": 8
      },
      {
          "id": "561",
          "count": "1",
          "month": 9
      },
      {
          "id": "561",
          "count": "-1",
          "month": 9
      }
  ];
  
const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
   if (acc[`${item.id}-${item.month}`]) {
      acc[`${item.id}-${item.month}`] = {
        ...acc[`${item.id}-${item.month}`],
        count: `${parseInt(acc[`${item.id}-${item.month}`].count) + parseInt(item.count)}`
      }
   } else {
    acc[`${item.id}-${item.month}`] = item;
   }
   return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: You are concatenating the `count` value not adding ...

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I updated that part in my solution, I didn't see that count was a string in OP question

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using Array.prototype.reduce to create a new array and Array.prototype.find to check if the current value is already present in the new array

```js
const arr = [
  {
          "id": "561",
          "count": "1",
          "month": 7
      },
      {
          "id": "561",
          "count": "1",
          "month": 7
      },
      {
          "id": "561",
          "count": "-1",
          "month": 8
      },
      {
          "id": "561",
          "count": "1",
          "month": 9
      },
      {
          "id": "561",
          "count": "-1",
          "month": 9
      }
  ]

const result = arr.reduce((acc, value) => {
  const index = acc.findIndex(({id, month}) => id === value.id && month === value.month);
  if( index > -1 ) {
    acc[index]['count'] += Number(value.count);
  }
  else {
    acc.push({...value, count: Number(value.count)});
  }
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: `id` of 561 and `month` 7 should have `count` of 2...

Comment: @RobinMackenzie ah, I've missed that part in the question. thanks